# Error in Creating an Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a method to save data into an sqlite database , but it seems i have a problem using it.

```
    public void saveDataInDB(double latitude, double longitude) {


        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + " (CurrentDate VARCHAR(20), Lat DOUBLE, Lng DOUBLE, Alt DOUBLE, Speed DOUBLE);");


        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES('" + latitude + "', '" + longitude + "');");


        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        c.moveToLast();


        db.close();
        db.getPath();

    }
```

This method worked fine when i used it in a location application to save the location , when i tried to re-use it in another application to save another values it didn't work. It produces an error "MODE_PRIVATE can't resolve to a variable.I have changed the parameters to fit to my new application , i only having one parameter instead of longitude and latitude.

Any help , all i want is to save a value called "sum" into the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to save only one value, use shared preferences instead of using database. But, if you are going to use database it would much better to use `SQLiteOpenHelper`. you can check it in this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Also concerning your code, i'm not sure where are you using this code but you have to use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`